# Java:Change String content

Tags: java, database, string

In my application user give the name of the database file where he/she want to create database file and my application create database at that location with user provided name.
With the help of FileChooser user give the name of database and when he/she click on save button then one database file created at that place.
Code:

```
public class StringSpilt1 {
  public static void main(String[] argv)
    throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);
    System.out.println(fileChooser.getSelectedFile());
    createDatabase((fileChooser.getSelectedFile()).toString());

  }

private static void createDatabase(String string) {
    String databaseName = string;
//      String databaseName = "D:\\MSAccessProject/GRISS.mdb";
        Database database = createDatabase(databaseName);
    // rest of the code
}
}
```

now the problem is that **(fileChooser.getSelectedFile()).toString()** return the path in this way:

**D:\MSAccessProject\GRISS.mdb**

And for creating database I need path in this way:
**D:\\MSAccessProject/GRISS.mdb"**

How can I solve this problem.

Comment: Why do you need `D:\\MSAccessProject/GRISS.mdb` instead of `D:\MSAccessProject\GRISS.mdb`? I suspect there is a different problem (probably in `createDatabase`) that needs fixing.

Comment: No other problem is there. If I want to create Database file then I need to give path(url) where I need to create database.
Database will created if I change this code by: Database database = createDatabase("D:\\MSAccessProject/GRISS.mdb");
but (fileChooser.getSelectedFile()).toString() return path in this way: D:\MSAccessProject\GRISS.mdb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the Solution:

```
String str=(fileChooser.getSelectedFile()).toString();
System.out.println("old:\t"+str);
String aaa= str.replaceAll("\\\\", "/");
System.out.println("new:\t"+aaa);
StringBuilder myName = new StringBuilder(aaa);
myName.setCharAt(2, '\\');
System.out.println("Final String:\t"+myName.toString());
```

And then I need to pass this string to:

```
createDatabase(myName.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use double back slashes "`\\`" or single forward slash "`/`". I guess that should solve your problem. After getting the path from `fileChooser.getSelectedFile()).toString();` perform the following operation:

```
path.replace("\","/");
```